# Updating application using InstallShield in VS2012

Tags: c#

I am trying to update an application using the Install Shield project in visual studio 2012.

I have read tons of articles/stackoverflow questions about it, and every single one gives the same steps for updating an existing application:

- Increment product version
- Change Product Code
- Build Setup

So I do exactly that. First I build my application, then I build the setup. I find the setup, and I run it. It installs the application as expected.

Then I make a minor change to my application (changing the background color for example), then I:

- I build the application
- Increment Product version from 1.00.0000 to 1.00.0001
- Change the Product Code - I Click the {...} to automatically generate a new one
- Make sure the Update Code is the same
- Build the setup

Go to the same directory I found the setup in before, and run the setup. It indicates that it installs, but then when I run the program, it is the original program - and in my Control Panel > Programs, there is now 2 instances of the application. And in the install directory of the application, it is still the original files.

I have clicked the resequence RemoveExistingProducts, and still the same thing.

**edit**: I am just using the basic version of InstallShield that came with VS2012

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 5):

As stated within the Upgrade Paths section of InstallShield within VS2012:

If you have released earlier versions of your product and you want to ensure that end users are able to upgrade to the current version without manually installing the earlier version and then also installing the current version, use the Upgrade Paths view to indicate upgrade information.

So in order to upgrade any previous installations, you need to add your application's Upgrade Code to the 'Upgrade Paths'. You can do this from the Solution Explorer:

[InstallShield Setup Project] -> Organize Your Setup -> Upgrade Paths

From that tab, you will right-click on the 'Upgrade Paths' option on the left side of the center pane, and select 'New Upgrade Path...'. You will then be presented with an option to select an installer (.exe or .msi) for your project which will populate the Upgrade Code field. Make sure you set the Min and Max Version fields to specify which versions of your application that you'd like your new installer to upgrade. If you'd like the new installer to upgrade any installed version of your application, then simply set the 'Include Max Version' and 'Include Min Version' fields to no.

You should now be set to build your solution, and when running the new installer, you'll find that you will no longer run into the problems you've specified.